# One cell in my table needs to be split into two equal 'columns'

Tags: html, css, html-table, split, cell

One cell in a large table needs to be split into 2 equal-width 'columns'. I realize I can use `colspan`, but rather than have every other cell in the table span so that *this one cell* is split, I'm looking for inline-or-CSS alternatives, like float, etc. Here is a screenshot of what I'm trying to get:

[image: SPLIT ONE CELL]

Comment: When you split the content of a cell, do you plan on keeping that change?

Answer (score 0):

Just put two spans or divs in the cell and use css to style them.

```css
table {
  with: 100%;
}

td div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

td div:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
}

td div:last-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Normal cell</td>
      <td><div>Split</div><div>Cell</div></td>
      <td>Normal cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: adrian . . . well I've gotten further along with your helpful code but it doesn't work. See my (CODEPEN)https://codepen.io/semicodin/pen/MPVWyK).